# opencv - imread returns false size

Tags: c++, opencv, imread

I have a 720x1280 image. I try to load ans show it. But I see 90 degree rotated image(1280x720).

My simple code is :

```
cout << "Size = " << imread(fileName).size() << endl;
```

The result is :

```
Size = [1280x720]
```

[image]

How can I load and show big size image using opencv? I use opencv 2.4.10.

Comment: I assume you are on Windows and you have flipped it using "right click-> rotate", right?

Comment: No, I haven't. The photo was taken from my smart phone. I use windows.

Comment: mmm then I do not know.. I mentioned that because I had similar problem that if I flipped it from windows the image will shown as flipped in windows but it actually does not ( Ithink windows makes some change to the metadata not the actual data) good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The image is probably encoded that way. Smartphones typically encode images the same direction every time regardless of how it is held but will add meta data to the image so that the viewing program can show it the intended way. OpenCV does not take this meta data into account. You can rotate the image yourself though. (Use 1 instead of 0 if the image becomes upside down).

```
cv::transpose(image, image);
cv::flip(image, image, 0);
```

If you prefer to modify the image on disk instead you can use [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/). Simply open the image and save/export it. Gimp will use the meta data when opening the image but re-encode the image without it.

Comment: Same issue for Windows built-in flipping.. So annoying -_-